# BLE scan() not returning complete advertisement payload

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, micropython

Summary: Micropython Bluetooth BLE scan() does not return the complete advertisement payload, specifically missing "Complete Local Name".

Setup:

- ESP32-WROOM-32
- esp32-idf4-20210202-v1.14
- Micropython GitHub [examples/bluetooth/ble_simple_central.py](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_simple_central.py) (as basis)

I'm trying to scan and discover a Xiaomi temperature device using Micropython. Using the Nordic Semiconductor APP [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=no&gl=US) on my phone displays the following advertised raw data:

```
020106111695FE30585B05015646D238C1A42801000B094C5957534430334D4D43
```

Broken up, this decodes to the following details

```
len==2,  0x01==FLAGS:           0201 06 
len==17, 0x16==SERVICE_DATA:    1116 95FE30585B05015646D238C1A4280100
len==11, 0x09==NAME:            0B09 4C5957534430334D4D43
```

The last element is the 0x09 (Complete Local Name), but the problem is that Micropython ble.scan() does not return the complete advert. payload. When scanning in Micropython, the **last element (name) is missing**. The raw data returned in `adv_data` is:

```
020106111695fe30585b05015646d238c1a4280100
```

I just made a small modification to `_irq(...)` of [ble_simple_central.py](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/examples/bluetooth/ble_simple_central.py) to simply display all discovered devices and to illustrate the problem:

```
    def _irq(self, event, data):
        if event == _IRQ_SCAN_RESULT:
            addr_type, addr, adv_type, rssi, adv_data = data
            addr_h = binascii.hexlify(bytes(addr)).decode('utf-8')
            adv_data_h = binascii.hexlify(bytes(adv_data)).decode('utf-8')
            print('addr_type: {}, addr: {}, adv_type: {}, rssi: {}, adv_data: {}'.format(addr_type, addr_h, adv_type, rssi, adv_data_h))
```

The output (for the Xiaomi device) is:

```
addr_type: 0, addr: a4c138d24656, adv_type: 0, rssi: -68, adv_data: 020106111695fe30585b05015646d238c1a4280100
```

Am I forgetting something?
Does the Xiaomi misbehave?
Does Micropython or the Bluetooth specificationrequire that the advertise payload to be formatted differently?

Comment: Could it be that your micropython does not include "scan response" payload, but only the "advertising data" payload?

Comment: Yes, of course! Thanks a lot for the tip. I realized that Micropython ble.scan(...) can specify if SCAN_RESULT should be included or not.

Comment: I upvoted the comment, but accidently udone it, an now I cannot re-upvote it. Sorry, Emil.

Answer (score 3):

Based on comment and great tip from [Emil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556495/emil), the solution was to set parameter 'active' in BLE.gap_scan(..., active=True) to receive scan responses in the results.

This makes the irq callback receive 2 separate messages with different `adv_types`:

- 0x00 - ADV_IND - containing the advertising data
- 0x04 - SCAN_RSP - containing the name

Doc ref: [Observer Role (Scanner)](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/ubluetooth.html?highlight=bluetooth#observer-role-scanner)